# C# static variable passed through constructor is cleared

Tags: c#

In my aspx.cs page I have a int static variable and Im passing it to a constructor of another class, in which I have a function that increments static variable. However, when execution is done and when Im back to my aspx.cs page Im loosing my static variable value.

aspx.cs page

```
public static int one;

//Im creating an object to test class
Test t = new Test(ref int one);
t.Increment();
```

Test Class.cs

```
public class Test {

int _one;

public Test(ref one) {
  this._one = one;
}

public void Increment() {
_one++;
} 

}
```

Edit

I have two aspx.cs pages that holds a static variable and a Test class, which has an Increment function, increments the static variables of aspx.cs class. I tried passing by ref when I create an object of Test class but no use. Can someone suggest me best design for this purpose.

one.aspx.cs

```
public static int one;

//Im creating an object to test class
Test t = new Test(ref int one);
t.Increment();
```

Two.aspx.cs

```
public static int Two;

//Im creating an object to test class
Test t = new Test(ref int Two);
t.Increment();
```

Test Class

```
public class Test {

int _value;

public Test(ref one) {
    this._value = one;
}

public void Increment() {
   _value++;
} 

}
```

Comment: You are not holding a reference(pointer) to static variable `one` in your `Test` class (and you can't).

Comment: Your technique wouldn't work in any case in ASP.NET. If you could increment the static variable, you would increment it for all users of the page.

Comment: Why do you want it to be `static` variable? what is that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Rahul My increment function sets an order to the variables Im passing from my aspx.cs page and this order will be used in further step present in aspx.cs page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how good this would be but have your `Increment` function accept the classname as parameter like

```
public class Test {

public void Increment(string class_name) 
{
if(class_name == "One")
 One.one++;
else
Two.two++;
} 

}
```

then in your .aspx page call it like

```
//one.aspx.cs
t.Increment("One");


//Two.aspx.cs

t.Increment("Two");
```

Answer (score 3):

Your static variable never changes its value. You pass it by reference to the `Test` constructor, but then you just copy its value to `_one`. And the change of `_one` within `Increment` has no impact on the static variable `one`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
int _one;

public Test(ref one) {
  this._one = one;
}
```

Even though you pass a *reference* to the variable `one`, you are assigning it's *value* to `this._one`.  So when you increment you are incrementing the local field and not the reference that was passed in.

Comment: How do I increment my static variable in this order?

Comment: @user2412230, if your sole idea is to increment that static variable then in your increment method just say `classname.one++;` where `classname` is the name of the class where `one` declared.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Trying to hold a reference to a static member to mutate it sounds like a strange design.

Comment: @Rahul In my Test class the Increment function is being used by two different aspx.cs pages. These two aspx.cs classes uses Increment function to increment its local static variables. Can u suggest me any solution for this?

Comment: @user2412230, Yeah; use `sessions` instead of static variable .